Explicitly call an overloaded method
I have an inheritance chain:
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

In my interface, I define methods with the same name taking each one of the above classes:
class Interface {
public:
    virtual void Foo(Base&) = 0;
    virtual void Foo(Derived&);
};

My intention is to provide a default implementation for the second method, which is naturally just relaying the object to the first method:
void Interface::Foo(Derived& obj) {
    Foo((Base&) obj);
}

What is the right approach to achieve the desired effect?

Why do you need both versions of Foo() at all?  If you remove the Foo(Derived &) entirely, then Some_Interface.Foo(Some_Derived) will work.

Foo(static_cast<Base&>(obj)); would be the preferred way to cast, instead of the C-style case.  And ditto to what Peter said.

@Peter, because it allows some implementations to implement different things once overriding the second function. Think of writing to terminal with colors and omitting colors when writing to file.

Why not provide suitable virtual functions in Base, override as needed them in Derived, make Interface::Foo(Base &) non-virtual, and use Base polymorphically?

@Peter, in reality Base and Derived are library classes, and I can't change their implementation.

If needed, void Foo(Base&) can still check dynamic type for extra/other implementation.
